# How to deal with object from Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble dealing with object type in realtime database in firebase. I want to convert it into json format. I searched but found none regarding this topic. To be clearer, I am using `onValue` to listen for this `object` like this:

```
currentRef.onValue.listen((event) {
  setState(() {
    currentReading = event.snapshot.value.toString();
  });
```

But I don't need to convert it to String, I want to deal with data within this Object.

Data printed:

```
{
"2022 11 21": 400,
  "2022 11 22": 232,
  "2022 11 23": 500
}
```

Data Type: `IdentityMap<String, dynamic>`

Comment: could you print("value=${event.snapshot.value}"); and show us result?

Comment: if you are asking about the type of value it prints, it prints "IdentityMap<String, dynamic>
" @eamirho3ein

Comment: As for the value, it prints values like this "{test: 0, test2: 2}"

Comment: what do you want to do with this data?

Comment: I need to like loop over specific data with specific keys, for example I will save data with keys equal to date it was uploaded, I will get all data in specific date and use its values to represent it in graphs @eamirho3ein

Comment: thanks, could you edit your question and add the real data that you print?

Comment: The data you get is incorrect, two keys in a map literal shouldn't be equal.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the JSON that exists at `currentRef` (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: just added the JSON content from my database @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your specific data this way:

```
currentRef.onValue.listen((event) {
  String yourSpecificDate = "2022 11 21";
  var result = Map.fromEntries(
        event.snapshot.children.entries.where((element) => element.key == yourSpecificDate));

  print("result = $result");//result = {2022 11 21: 223}
  print("value = ${result.entries.first.value}");//value = 223
});
```

Comment: I don't know what is happening, "entries" is not defined in event

Comment: what exact error did you get?

Comment: I got it, it should be like this --> "event.snapshot.children.where((element) => false);"

Comment: sorry I forgot to add it, you are right.